# LWC Model Height/Width Issue

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, static-resources

I have created a custom quick action model which has custom min-width defined in Static resource CSS.

i have loaded that static resource using **loadStyle(this, QuickActionFullScreen);** in renderCallback method

The component works well but when I close that model and open another model like Create record, Edit record or another quick action model same height applies to it which I don't want.

**How I can force my static resource to apply CSS to only my component?**

**Static Resource CSS**

```css
 .slds-modal__container{
 min-width: 90vw;
     }
   
     .cuf-content {
             padding: 0 0rem !important;
     }
     .slds-p-around--medium {
         padding: 0rem !important;
     }       
     .slds-modal__content{
         overflow-y:hidden !important;
         height:unset !important;
         max-height:unset !important;
     min-height : 40vw !important;
                 
     }   

     .slds-modal__container {
         margin: 0 auto;
         width: 95%;
         min-width: 99vw !important;
     max-width: 1500px !important;   
     }
     .slds-modal__header {
         color: white ;
         background: #1398c3;
     }
    
     
     .slds-button_icon-inverse
     {
         display : block ;
     }
```

```javascript
import { LightningElement, api, wire,track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import QuickActionFullScreen from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/QuickActionFullScreen';
renderedCallback()
    {
             loadStyle(this, QuickActionFullScreen);
            loadStyle(this,lwcGeneralCSS);
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

> How I can force my static resource to apply CSS to only my component?

You can't. That's one reason why this method isn't recommended; your styles *will* break the rest of Salesforce.

From a practical perspective, you should be able to make your component [headless](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_headless) and display a custom modal that you build yourself (but I haven't tested this), or you can build a custom modal that breaks out of the standard modal (don't forget to use [CloseActionScreenEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_quick_actions_screen) when you're done).